# javascript - Executing Code in code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just wanted to ask, it this possible to execute javascript code from user input? For example: User enters his Javascript code in `<textarea id="test">`. Then with JavaScript i get his input  with `var userInput = $('#test').val();`. And is it possible to execute javascript code from that string? If it is possible, please tell me how.

~Regards

Comment: you can use `eval` to execute strings as code.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Comment: more specifically: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#Don.27t_use_eval.21 ... "eval() is a dangerous function"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to do this with the eval() function:

```
eval(userInput);
```

or by creating a function and then invoking it.

```
var fun = new Function(userInput);
fun.apply(window);
```

Comment: Where do you find an `invoke()` method on a javascript Function object?  In JS, you invoke a function with `()` like `fun()`.

Comment: Sorry, it's apply (or call)

Comment: You only need to use `.call()` if you want to control the `this` pointer and you only need to use `.apply()` if you want to pass an array of arguments rather than just listing them.  Otherwise, you can just use `fun()`.